# Git: Having server git repo 'push' to /public_html

Tags: git, git-remote

I'm in the process of learning how to get a new git repo set up. I just have previously used git repos in the pass that were set up.

Goal:
I'm trying to figure out how the set-up process to this works. I have it so my local can be pushed to my remote git repo successfully. I'd like to have the remote git repo 'push' to where my live site is at now, but only a certain folder. Is this possible?

My git repo file setup:
/.git
/trunk (where my site files are, I want this pushable into my /pubic_html files on the server)
/resources (just psd's and such, I don't want this in my /public_html files on the server)
/db-backups (just database backups, I don't want these in my /public_html files on the server)

I would  log into my remote webserver, cd into `~/public_html/` and run 'get pull' and have just all my site files/folders be updated from my repo. (hope this make sense)

My current setup follows:

---

My local git config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:ref/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://mygituser@website.com/~/opt/git/mywebsiterepo.git
```

---

My remote git config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:ref/remotes/origin/*
```

Location: `~/opt/git/myrepo.git`  (where I ran git `init --bare --shared`)

---

My remote website git config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:ref/remotes/origin/*
        url = ~/opt/git/mywebsiterepo.git
```

Location: `~/public_html`

### Update

I just thought of a way I need to do this correctly with having my git `/trunk` folder to be the **only** thing 'pull'ed inside my `/public_html` folder for my live site.

- removed my old git clone of my repo that was in `~/public_html`
- created a new git clone to new folder`~/git/myrepo/`
- created a Symlink `public_html -> /home/mywebsite/git/myrepo/trunk`

So now my `/trunk` folder with all my website files is the only thing inside my life `/public_html` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to setup a [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks.html) that automatically does the pulling for you:

```
 cd ~/opt/git/myrepo.git/hooks
```

then create a file called `post-receive` and add something along the files of this in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=$HOME/public_html --git-dir=$HOME/opt/git/myrepo.git/ pull
```

then `chmod +x post-receive`.

There's a lengthy article @ https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps if you want to find out more details.

Comment: Good to know. To make sure I understand this all correctly. This hook `post-receive` needs to be created in my git repo that is located: ~/public_html ? Not my version control repo.

Comment: I updated my question above after I thought of a way to only have my /truck files be pushed to /public_html.

Comment: It's exactly the same concept, you just remove the `--git-dir=$HOME/opt/git/myrepo.git/` part.

Comment: Got it, played a bit more with this yesterday and grasped how the process to this works. Thanks a ton for the help.